# Using the same application interface figures in both journal and conference papers?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, conference

I am about to submit a conference paper before a journal paper about the same work, which involves the creation of a web interface.

Is it OK to put the same screenshots of the application interface in both the conference and later into the journal paper? Or it will be considered the same work and hence rejected by the journal?

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be fine, but you should take some precautions. If the publishers of both are the same, it will be easier.

In the journal paper, since it comes later, cite the conference paper and note that the images are taken from it. This avoids any hint of self plagiarism.

If the conference takes over copyright of your work, then you also have to contend with that. Typically an author would get permission (a license) for such a use, even after giving up copyright. If it isn't obvious, then make a specific request of the conference publisher for the use you intend.

Comment: At least in the US I think that a screenshot is unlikely to be creative enough to actually be copyright protected. (Though it may reproduce copyrightable elements of the interface itself.) Of course, getting permission to reproduce a figure tends to be easy enough and would remove all doubts.